# What is the font in the headings on Lovely Things?

Tags: font-identification

I've just run across [Lovely Things](http://www.lovelythingsstore.com/), and I can't for the life of me figure out what the font is in their headings and navigation links. What is it? I only ask, of course, because it's embedded solely in images.

[image: Screenshot of Lovely Things]

I tried [WhatTheFont](http://new.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/), but couldn't get any of the images to take.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That site uses [Cufón](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/).

The font is converted to a javascript file, and this font is **FertigoPro-Regular**

[image: FertigoPro-Regular]

Link to the original font: http://www.exljbris.com/fertigo.html
(It is free and you can download from that link).